# How to strengthen conditions when $f$ is uniformly continuous $f'$ must be bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-continuity

Show that a twice differentiable function $\mathbb R  \to \mathbb R$ whose second derivative is bounded is uniformly continuous if and only if its first derivative is bounded.